# Install futhark?

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I have tried to follow the official guide(https://futhark.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#linux-installation) but I am very far from a Ubuntu/Linux expert.

I cannot install brew on my Ubuntu and I have no idea what the other options are. Can any of you wizards help me out? What steps would you take to install it?

Comment: We don't care which guide you "folliwed". We care about the commands you actually executed, and the results. "Following a guide" doesn't tell us about your possible typos, omitted steps, or actual errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall git haskell-stack libtinfo-dev libgmp-dev
git clone https://github.com/diku-dk/futhark.git
cd futhark
stack setup
stack build
stack install
```